# How to query Parser users who are not friend of current user?

Tags: android, list, parsing, search, relation

this may be simple to you but I am stucked for hours. My Parse User have a relation I setup which is called "Friendsrelation". Now I wanted to load the list of user who are not a friend with the current user so that  the currect user can send a request to add him as friend. I cant seems to be able to query users who are not friend (means not in friendsrelation) with currect user. Hope you can help me out here. Much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this query :-

```
 String qry = "select userid FROM users WHERE Not EXISTS (SELECT friendId  FROM friendsrelation WHERE friendsrelation.friendId  =users.userID and friendsrelation.myid = currentuserID)";
            Cursor objCursor = db.rawQuery(qry,null);

        ArrrayList<Long> friendsids = new ArrrayList<Long>();
        if ((objCursor != null) && (objCursor.getCount() > 0)) {
                        objCursor.moveToFirst();
                        while (objCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        friendsids.add(objCursor.getLong(objCursor.getColumnIndex("userid ")));
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that my customer adapter is taking in parse user instead of string, (public SearchMateAdapter(Context context, List<ParseUser> requests) ), I have tried to convert the above arraylist <long> to list<parseuser> but it didn't work. Appreciate your guidance on this. Thanks.

Comment: use ArrrayList<parseuser> listParseuser= new ArrrayList<parseuser>(); and get ids as parseuser objparseuser = new parseuser(); objparseuser .userid =objCursor.getLong(objCursor.getColumnIndex("userid "));  and add this object to parseuserlist as listParseuser.add(objparseuser);

Comment: Also I am trying to query from Parse and not SQL. It seems it doesnt work. Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Giru for your reply. Would you able to update the code as I am quite lost with the above on Cursor (Cursor objCursor = db.rawQuery(qry,null); returned error)

Comment: Yes, but I think the code you given is for SQL and not for me as I am using Parse Query...it returns lots of error in Arraylist, etc. Do you do something for Parse Query instead? Something like Parse user = new Parse.getQuery().where....

Comment: the code is for sqlite,You may use similar for parse

Comment: I am afraid I dont know how to do so because I never done sql lite query before :( do you mind to help me out?

Comment: Anyone can help me out here?